# How to convert a byte array with hexadecimal contents to string with decimal in c#

Tags: c#

Language : C#

Basically i have a Byte array which contains hexadecimal contents.

I want to convert it into a String and the hexadecimal contents should also be converted into Decimal contents.

My final string should contain Equivalent Decimal Values of the Hexa Decimal values contained in the initial Byte Array.

I converted byte array to string using 
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString

But how to convert the Hex to Decimal ?
Even if we can do it in multiple steps it is not a problem.

sorry to ask silly doubts , please Spare.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you give examples - does converting to decimal mean { 0x1, 0x0, 0x3 } become the string "1,0,3" or "259" or "719"?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you mean.

Byte arrays just contain byte values - they're just numbers. In other words:

```
byte x = 0x20;
byte y = 32;
```

are exactly the same - they both just set the value to be 32.

Now, if you want to convert a byte array into a number, look at [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) and its methods like [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32.aspx). That will convert the byte array into a number (an `int` in that particular case) - you can then just call `ToString()` on the number to get a decimal representation as a string.

How many bytes is your original data? That will be a key factor in determining which `BitConverter` method to call. You will also need to know the endianness of the data - if `BitConverter` in "normal" .NET is little endian; you might be interested in the `EndianBitConverter` class in my [MiscUtil library](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) if your data is really big-endian.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to create a comma separated string of the decimal numbers - e.g:

```
byte[] hexValues = { 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF };
string decimalValuesAsStringList = string.Join(",", hexValues.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray());
```

...or like this:

```
char[] hexCharacters = { '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
byte[] hexValues = hexCharacters.Select(c => Convert.ToByte(c)).ToArray();
string decimalValuesAsStringList = string.Join(",", hexValues.Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(((char)i).ToString(), 16).ToString()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array really contains the character codes of the hexadecimal representation of numbers, then you don't have to bother with decoding. As the character codes for those characters are the same in all regular encodings, you can just cast the bytes to characters.

I wrote an extension that parses a stream of characters into a stream of bytes:

```
static class Hex {

    public static IEnumerable<byte> ParseHex(this IEnumerable<char> chars) {
        int buffer = 0;
        bool first = true;
        foreach (char c in chars) {
            int b = (c - '0') % 32;
            if (b > 9) b -= 7;
            if (first) {
                buffer |= b << 4;
            } else {
                yield return (byte)(buffer | b);
                buffer = 0;
            }
            first = !first;
        }
        if (!first) {
                yield return (byte)buffer;
        }
    }

}
```

(If someone recognises part of the code, it's based on my code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684925/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-a-hexidecimal-string-to-a-byte-array-net/685103#685103) answer.)

Usage:

```
byte[] data = { 48, 70, 51, 67, 70, 56, 48, 55, 57, 49 };

string result = string.Join(",",
    data.Cast<char>().ParseHex().Select(b => b.ToString()).ToArray()
);
```