# Writing a large string to file

Tags: c#, arrays, byte

I have been trying to write very long strings of hex (8mb worth or 16 million characters) to a file using:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, hexarray);
```

If I try to compile I get an error:

> out of logical memory

What would be the best way write this hex to file without it throwing a error?

I was thinking break the string into multiple strings and add hex1 then hex2 at the EOF but before trying this I realized I would still add to much string to the memory.

EDIT i should specify my code a bit more

```
string z = "2412341A4D2341341234141";  <--this is alot longer tho

File.WriteAllBytes("C:/user/asdf/setup.sdf"), StringToByteArray(z));

public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: where are you getting the strings from? is it in memory or is it generated or are you copying a file?

Comment: The hex is from a file i copied the hex and made it into a string

Comment: Are you trying to write bytes or character?  Never use string from binary data. A c# character is two bytes with a private property indicating if the character is one or two bytes.  So 8 mb characters is someplace between 8mb and 16 mb bytes.  So you have to use Encoding.XXX.GetBytes() to convert a string to a byte array.  If you have binary data never convert to strings using Encoding.  Instread write binary data with BinaryWriter().

Comment: @jdweng: There are plenty of cases where you need to represent binary data in text form though, usually either as hex or base64. In neither of those cases would you use `Encoding.GetBytes`, nor do you need `BinaryWriter` for them. It's unclear where the OP's data is actually coming from - we don't know whether the hex part is necessary here - but there are certainly cases where it is.

Comment: thanks for the input @JonSkeet

Comment: "The hex is from a file i copied the hex and made it into a string" - why? Please give more information about why you've converted the data from binary to text form to start with. Sometimes that's necessary, sometimes it's not - we can't tell with so little context.

Comment: the basics of my application is to delete my original secret programs in .exe format and be able to restore them from hex by entering the correct password and clicking a button.  the code works as set but only with smaller files the reason i had to ask here is my test size was 30kb(worked perfect),  now my final applications i want to build are 8mb(i get error out of logical memory occurs)

Comment: How did you get bytes into string? string z = "2412341A4D2341341234141";  You can convert this back to bytes but it may not be necessary.  Your mistake may be that you incorrectly converted to a string.

Comment: i used hxd to pull all the bytes, then notepad to replace all the spaces, and the final proccess that i thought was neccessary StringToByteArray to convert it back to hex to be rewritten.  the hxd and notepad steps are not convenient but if i need the files on a different computer i can simply execute this and it will remake them without having to hunt them down again

Comment: @Ragekillen: A better way of including the file content in your application would be to make it an embedded resource file.

Comment: Ok thank you @JonSkeet i will look into embedding it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: As an aside, that's also a very inefficient way of converting a hex string into bytes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684925/ for better alternatives.

Comment: thanks again i can see that having future use  :)

Comment: Don't store binary as hex strings. Store binary as binary. Use hex strings only when displaying to humans.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking into a [`FileStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) and keeping the complete set of data out of memory if you can help it. If you are reading from a file and writing to another one, the streams will provide a buffered way of doing so without loading each file in its entirety into memory.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question is misleading: You get a compiler error. This has nothing to do with writing the file. 
Probably the compiler can't handle your string in the source code because it is too long. Consider storing it in a textfile, and reading that from your code... If you want, you can include that file in your resources. After processing, you can use one of the techniques below to write it to a new file.

Answer (score -1):

this was answered.  the correct way of doing it is adding the files as resources then extract them to a directory using

```
File.WriteAllBytes(path, System.Properties.Resources.core);
```

thanks to @jonskeet for pointing this out

this isn't exactly what i originally wanted but it has the same results

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. The answer to that is in Johan's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46127767/ Including executable files in resources is quite inefficient, FWIW. Better usually to include them as distinct files alongside the executable.

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
            string hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            string z = "2412341A4D23413412341419";

            List<byte> resutls = new List<byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < z.Length; i += 2)
            {
                byte data = (byte)((hex.IndexOf(z.Substring(i, 1)) << 4) + hex.IndexOf(z.Substring(i + 1, 1)));
                resutls.Add(data);
            }
```

Comment: This will result in the same compile error reported in the question. The string literal is too large.

Comment: David : you are making a bad assumption.  Linq will use a lot more memory the a straight for loop.   So my code will work when linq fails.

Comment: It's a compile time error...... The code is irrelevant. It never executes, because it doesn't compile. It's the size of the string literal.

Comment: Or did you succeed to compile the code with a large test string?

Comment: Why would you ever compile with a large string?  The input normally would come from a different source.   Compiling a large string doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well no, but that was what was clearly asked in the question. You need to speak to the question asked.

Comment: David : You may another bad assumption.  The question wasn't about writing data to a large string.  It was about writing to a file.

Comment: I did not say anything about writing to a large string.  I did not assume anything. I **read the question**. *If I try to compile I get an error"* And `string z = "2412341A4D2341341234141";  <--this is alot longer tho` And *"8mb worth or 16 million characters"* And then in comments: *"now my final applications i want to build are 8mb"* It's important here to answer the question that was asked, not to answer the question that you would prefer to have been asked.

Comment: Read again.  The real question is :"I have been trying to write very long strings of hex (8mb worth or 16 million characters) to a file using".

Comment: Yes, I read that. However, there is a compile error. Do you know the difference between a compile error and a runtime error? I think you do. The compile error is because the asker is trying to specify a string literal of immense size. Whilst the .net runtime could handle it, the compiler does not handle it. Instead of letting your pride take over, consider perhaps trying to replicate the scenario.

Comment: You are putting the horse before the cart.  When a person is using the wrong methods(s) and getting an exception you do not fix the exception which is not part of the problem.  You give the person the correct method.

Comment: Right. So why not do that? You perpetuate the mistake in your answer because you still have the long string declared as a literal. In fact in your answer you do neither.  You don't work around the problem presented in the question, nor do you propose the correct method.